# SQL Server to DB2 Conversion: Migration Toolkit Issues

Tags: sql-server, migration, db2, toolkit

I am trying to convert from MS SQL Server 2008 Express to DB2 9.7.

I have installed IBM Migration Toolkit and successfully connected to my SQL Server database (hosted locally).

I tried to extract from database, keeping all default data mappings, but when I extract, I get the following (for all the tables) - Has anyone had a problem like this where all column types are null with Migration Toolkit?

At first I thought it might be because I am using the Express edition of SQL Server and maybe it couldn't see the column types under this application, but the fact that Name and Unit are null(50) and therefore it has understood that these columns have associated lengths makes me doubt this.

```
CREATE TABLE [Action] ([Id] null IDENTITY , [Name] null(50) NOT NULL , [UserId] null NOT NULL , [FreqId] null NOT NULL , [Quant] null NULL , [Unit] null(50) NULL , [Start] null NOT NULL , [End] null NOT NULL , [Created] null NOT NULL , [Modified] null NOT NULL , [Deleted] null NOT NULL )
```

Comment: The IBM MTK page doesn't mention MSSQL 2008, only 2000/2005. Are you sure what you're trying is supported?

Comment: Greg, I know this is almost an year later, but have you found a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently use [DCW(data conversation workbench) toolkit](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=swg-idcw&S_PKG=dl&lang=en_US&cp=UTF-8), it's very useful to get all the data table of SQL Server 2008.

You may try DCW. Remind to you: after installing plugin to DB2, you must add [driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=2505) of sql to DB2 (window->reference->data management -> connectivity> drive definitions)